# Permutation test in R

Tags: r, nonparametric, permutation-test

I have the following data for 10 subjects based on before and after measurements:

```
x <- c(12.9, 13.5, 12.8, 15.6, 17.2, 19.2, 12.6, 15.3, 14.4, 11.3) 
y <- c(12.7, 13.6, 12.0, 15.2, 16.8, 20.0, 12.0, 15.9, 16.0, 11.1)
```

and would like to perform a permutation test.

I used the `permTS(...)` to perform a two-sided t-test and obtained a value of `0.982`.

But I would like to use the `expand.grid(rep(x,k ))` by interchanging the before and after tags. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Given the numbers of possible permutations it is not possible to stimulate every permutation, hence why I would like to use expand.grid to check if the same result is obtained.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are saying is you would like to compare the paired t-test statistic to the distribution of such statistics obtained by independently switching all possible pairs of data.  There are $2^{10}=1024$ such switches, small enough to enable fast computation of the full distribution.

It is convenient in `R` to code this as a t-test for the difference between the two sets of data: instead of switching values, we merely need to negate them.

Let's first run the t-test:

```
x <- c(12.9, 13.5, 12.8, 15.6, 17.2, 19.2, 12.6, 15.3, 14.4, 11.3)
y <- c(12.7, 13.6, 12.0, 15.2, 16.8, 20.0, 12.0, 15.9, 16.0, 11.1)
(value <- t.test(x,y, paired=TRUE, alternative="two.sided"))
```

The statistic and p-value are $-0.213$ and $0.836$, as expected.  Now let's generate the permutation distribution (using `expand.grid` as requested):

```
perms <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(as.list(1:length(x)), function(i) c(-1,1)))
dist <- apply(perms, 1, function(p) t.test(p*(x-y), alt="t")$statistic)
```

(This takes $0.33$ seconds.)  As a quick check, let's graph the results:

```
hist(dist)
abline(v = value$statistic, col="Red", lwd=2)
```

[image: Permutation distribution]

Because the actual statistic is near the middle of the distribution and this is a two-sided test, the p-value looks approximately to be $0.9$ or so.  We can compute it:

```
sum(abs(dist) > abs(value$statistic)) / 2^length(x)
```

The result is $0.836$, the same as the t-distribution gave us.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I was n't sure on how to use expand.grid

Also just to add, I thought the permutations where 2^20, which did indeed take a while.

Many thanks

Comment: $2^{20}$ takes $6$ minutes :-).  (That's about the limit of my patience: by that time, we should be content to sample from the permutation distribution.)

Comment: Since the p-value is the probability for the test statistic being _at least as extreme_ as the empirically observed value, shouldn't the calculation be `sum(abs(dist) >= abs(value$statistic)) / 2^length(x)`, giving a p-value of 0.8710938?

Comment: @caracal That's a subtle point which I should have checked. The issue here is that the permutation distribution is *discrete*. It might be best to report that the p-value lies in the interval $[0.836, 0.871]$. The difference in this case is of course inconsequential, due to the large p-value(s), but it becomes of consequence when the interval spans one's threshold of significance. By reporting the full interval, you allow readers to apply (for instance) randomized tests.

Comment: Hi, just to follow up from that remark, why is the permutation test statistic value almost exactly the same value as the original t-test?
Given that this is a permutation of all possible values, should n't the t value be different, or is it a unique case for this data.

Thanks.

Comment: It's an accident that they are *so* close, but it is no accident that they are pretty close: the t-test is a good approximation to the permutation test in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a paired T-test since these are paired data, not a 2 sample test.

All possible permutations of pre-post data would be obtained using

`expand.grid(pre=x, post=y)`

And we know it's only a 2 by 100 matrix which is far from impossible. I don't know why you're replicating `x`, or what `k` is.

Comment: I wrote `expand.grid(rep(x,k))` as an example of the function. My question is how would I perform the test after obtaining this matrix, i.e. how to calculate the p-value and check if it matches the one from `permTS()`

Comment: This is where I got the data from:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/paired-students-t-test/